# find the number of strings in 2D array of strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Given an array of strings, i need to find out the number of strings in it.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522760/find-the-number-of-strings-in-an-array-of-strings-in-c)

but this doesn't work if i am passing this into a function.

here's the code i tried

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int f1(char* input1[])
{

    string s="";

    cout<<sizeof(input1)<<endl; //print 4
    cout<<sizeof(char*)<<endl;  //print 4
    int l=sizeof(input1) / sizeof(char*);
    //giving l=1 here but should be 8
}

int main()
{
    char *str2[]={"baba","sf","dfvf","fbfebgergrg","afvdfvfv","we","kkhhff","L"};
    int l=sizeof(str2) / sizeof(char*);
    cout<<l<<endl; //print 8
    cout<<sizeof(str2)<<endl; //print 32
    cout<<sizeof(char*)<<endl; //print 4
    f1(str2);
}
```

Comment: Do you know the compiler for which you have to solve that question?

Answer (score 8):

`sizeof(char*)` gives you the size of the `char*` pointer (which is 4 on your system).

`sizeof(str2)` is giving you the size of the array `str2`. There are 8 elements, each one is a pointer type. So the total size on your system is 8 x 4 = 32.

To get the length of a string, use `strlen`.

Do consider `std::vector<std::string>>` as an alternative in C++.

Comment: this is not working strlen(*input1) again giving 4 as output in function.

Comment: @Guru That's because `input1` is not an array. It's `char**`. Please read [How to use arrays in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c), especially the array-to-pointer conversion part.

Comment: @jrok:so what should i do to get the output 8 in function??

Comment: @Guru you need to pass the size as a parameter to the function. Check the link in my previous comment.

Comment: @jrok: actually it's an online contest question where i need this functionality. and there i cannot modify the given function prototype.
isn't there other way by which i don't need to modify the prototype of f1

Comment: @Guru If you're not allowed to change the prototype, then either you have a sentinel value to mark the end of the array, or the question is unsolvable.

Answer (score 1):

You can not know the length of an array if you only have a pointer to it. And you do have only a pointer because you cannot pass arrays by value. Arrays passed to a function will automatically decay to a pointer and the argument type `char* foo[]` is equivalent to `char** foo`. `size_of` doesn't help because it will only tell the size of the pointer itself.

Pass the length as an argument to `f1`. Or better yet, use `std::vector` or `std::array`.

> i cannot modify the given function prototype

Well, that's unfortunate. Then you must resort to some trickery. The simplest workaround is to store the length in a global variable instead of a function parameter.

Another possibility is a terminating value For example, always end the array with nullptr and never allow other elements to have that value. In the same way as c-strings are terminated with null character. Then you can stop iterating the array when come across nullptr. But I assume you cannot modify the array either.

Comment: that i know very well but actually it's an online contest question where i need this functionality. and there i cannot modify the given function prototype. isn't there other way by which i don't need to modify the prototype of f1

Comment: @Guru if you know that very well, then why are you asking why `size_of` doesn't work? Anyway,  you can resort to a global instead of a parameter.