# How to get string length in the array at compile time?

Tags: arrays, c, string

My question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522760/find-the-number-of-strings-in-an-array-of-strings-in-c) but from slightly different site.

Say we have the same array

```
const char *data[] = {
    "Str1",
    "Str Two",
    "Long string three",
};
```

Okay, compiler knows the length of array and we can get it in compile time: `sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0])`. At the same time compiler knows the size of each string, say the result of `strlen(data[1])` is actually known at compile time. But `strlen` is runtime call, and `sizeof[i]` will always return the `sizeof(char *)` value. Is there any way to get the length of each string of array **without** separate definition of each string as **variable** or **macro**?

Comment: `sizeof(data[0])/sizeof(data[0][0]);`

Comment: Compiler also knows `sizeof("whatever")`, so make your strings macros and use the macros to initialize, and also use `sizeof(macro)` where you need the sizes.

Comment: @hetepeperfan correct me if im wrong, but doesnt that just divide the size of a char pointer by the size of a char?

Comment: What's wrong with `strlen`?

Comment: @lulle is right, there something strange was suggested.

Comment: @lulle yep that's correct: https://godbolt.org/z/xGM5sWo5c

Comment: @EugeneSh. This is the same as extra variables. I want to avoid this.

Comment: @shved Macro is not a variable. It does not consume any memory.

Comment: @shved The problem is that your array is just an array of char pointers that point to a string literal. You can take the size of an array element, but you effectively get the size of a char pointer.

Comment: You can declare the strings seperately (e.g. const char string1[] = "abc"; const char string2[] = "def"), then make a a const array of char pointers that point to the string literals (e.g. 'const char *data[] = {string1, string2}') and a const array that holds the sizes (e.g. const size_t sizes[] = {sizeof(string1) , sizeof(string2)}')

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yep I know, some times variable does not consume any memory. I meant something else: it consume more effort to update an array. This is theoretical question. I found the case and suggested to think on it and maybe someone knows the perfect solution?

Comment: *Is there any way to get the length of each string of array without separate definition of each string as variable or macro* - Simply **NO**

Comment: `sizeof("whatever")` is a valid approach, but note that evaluates to 1 larger than `strlen("whatever")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE 2

Per your request, I will unequivocally state there is no part of the standard that allows you to obtain the length of a constant string except through the use of functions like `strlen`. You won't be able to create a macro that can do what you want.

You wrote:

> strlen is runtime call

It can be a run-time call or a compile-time call depending upon the compiler's optimization level, which, so far, no other person has mentioned. I'm a huge fan of letting the compiler do the work for me.

```
$ cat t.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *data[] = {"abc"};
    printf("sl=%ld\n", strlen(data[0]));
}
$ gcc t.c
$ nm a.out
                 U ___stack_chk_fail
                 U ___stack_chk_guard
0000000100008018 d __dyld_private
0000000100000000 T __mh_execute_header
0000000100003f00 T _main
                 U _printf
                 U _strlen
                 U dyld_stub_binder
$ gcc -O1 t.c
$ nm a.out
0000000100008008 d __dyld_private
0000000100000000 T __mh_execute_header
0000000100003f70 T _main
                 U _printf
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

UPDATE 1, prompted by chqrlie. See the instruction at 100003f7b. Altering the number of characters in that string will produce a different constant being loaded into the esi register.

```
$ objdump --disassemble-symbols=_main a.out

a.out:  file format mach-o 64-bit x86-64


Disassembly of section __TEXT,__text:

0000000100003f70 <_main>:
100003f70: 55                           pushq   %rbp
100003f71: 48 89 e5                     movq    %rsp, %rbp
100003f74: 48 8d 3d 33 00 00 00         leaq    51(%rip), %rdi  # 100003fae <dyld_stub_binder+0x100003fae>
100003f7b: be 03 00 00 00               movl    $3, %esi    #### This is the length of the string constant
100003f80: 31 c0                        xorl    %eax, %eax
100003f82: e8 05 00 00 00               callq   0x100003f8c <dyld_stub_binder+0x100003f8c>
100003f87: 31 c0                        xorl    %eax, %eax
100003f89: 5d                           popq    %rbp
100003f8a: c3                           retq
```

But even if it is a run-time call, there are two things to remember:

1. The cost of an optimized `strlen` call is quite small compared to many other operations that you would probably perform on the string.
2. You can minimize the frequency of your calls to `strlen` with responsible factoring.

Comment: The fact that `_strlen` is absent from the symbols does not mean it was computed at compile time... It might just have been inlined...

Comment: Perfect point! But again this is the compiler's decision, not the standard. We can not have any guarantee that ``strlen`` will be optimized.

Comment: I see, no one suggested absolutely working variant, so Eugeny said in comment the shortest answer is *NOT*, but your is the most close to solution. Can you please add short *You can not* answer?

Comment: @shved Do you mean "can you please say that there is no such way to implement this with a macro"?

Comment: @JeffHolt I mean there is no magic call like ``super_sizeof(data[i])`` which returns the size of string in array like ``sizeof(data)`` in compile time without adding extra variables or macros. But most of times compiler will optimize the ``strlen`` call to do exactly what I was asking for. To be clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can if you don't mind changing the definition of `data` a bit.

```cc
struct Elem
{
  size_t len;
  const char* str;
}

#define ARRAY_SIZE(x) (sizeof((x)) / sizeof((x)))
#define ELEM(x) ({ ARRAY_SIZE((x)) - 1, ((x)) })

const Elem[] data = {
  ELEM("Str1"),
  ELEM("Str Two"),
  ELEM("Long string three")
};
```

Comment: Nice try, but it useless in generic approach like ```memcpy(dst, data[1], sizeof(data[1]));```